# Speed up rigid body simulation baking?

Tags: baking, rigid-body-simulation, gpu, rigidbody

I'm making train simulations using rigid bodies and I would like to bake them more quickly so I can tweak parameters more efficiently than before.

Is it possible to force blender to use parallel computation on the gpu or to allocate more space for gpu computation and how would I doing it? (for rigid bodies baking)
Is this type of feature available in instable builds?

I could not find anything on the topic that could help me so I was asking myself if it is even possible in 2.9.

I'll be highly grateful for any help of any kind.
Best regards

PS: i'm also experiencing precision issues as you can witness on the folowing sample:
https://youtu.be/jhZhutF2qaw

---

EDIT 3:

Here is a video of one of the researchers from NVIDIA that worked on the project where he explains everything

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zzy6u1z_l9A

---

EDIT 2:

i've found this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F0QwAhUnpr4

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CPq87E1vD8k

https://matthias-research.github.io/pages/publications/PBDBodies.pdf

https://matthias-research.github.io/pages/publications/publications.html

It's capable of simulating in real time complex deformations, constraints and more.

Might be useful for my problem if it ends up available for blender.

---

EDIT 1:

as Rich Sedman asks, following is the setup of the rigid bodies in the scene:

First, I've made the railway as passive rigid body, the modeling was made according to a blueprint I found to have a rough idea of the size.

[image]

Then I have my wheels that are designed to fit with the rail. These are active rigid bodies.

There is a bogie that is a simple cube as you can witness on the wireframe screen shot.

The bogie and the two wheels are linked with a Hinge rigid body constraint forcing them to rotate.

The wagon itself is a low poly approximation of the actual train running on the RER A line in Paris (http://www.bianoti.com/rer-a.html)

[image]

The two bogies are linked to the cabin via the same hinge constraint, but on the vertical axis forcing it to rotate like intended.

The four cabins are made the same way and connected via the same constraint than with the bogie.

The wheels are motorized with 4 motor constraints that shares parameters with drivers. They are linked with the cabin. Only the two wheels on each extremity are motorized.

The force the motor transmits to the wheels is animated to help with accelerations and decelerations.

Every constraint is made with empties.

The baking is taking around 5 seconds to generate 30 frames. (This is really approximated since I've counted the 5 seconds my self). I'm generating 1600 frames each baking. It's not that slow but if I wish to create more complex scenarios I'll end up with 30 minutes generation which I had for previous version of the train.

PS: the wheels and the rail has been made using mirror and array modifiers

I might also add that the render is made with workbench but i don't think this changes the way baking works.

Comment: Please can you add some explanation as to what you have set up there? How have you setup the wheels? Are they attached with RB constraints? How are the carriages linked? (RB constraints?) what RB settings are you using different to the defaults? It shouldn’t be a particularly complicated setup and so shouldn’t be taking a long time to simulate IMO.

Comment: Additionally, I don’t think RB simulation can use the GPU anyway - I think it’s CPU only so I think the way forward is to determine why your situation is taking a long time (how long is it currently taking to bake?)

Comment: i'll edit my post to integrate all the informations on the setup

Comment: but every thing is rigid bodies and rigid body constraints

Comment: The screen shot was taken before i've finished some minor modifications to the wheel size so the hinge constraint empties are miss placed in the screenshot

Comment: I've understood something with the going crazy train problem, the friction was too hard for the speed and for the motor impulse at this specific time, all I did is reducing the max impulse value to 100 via the animation so now it does not go crazy.